# Sort matrix according to number of non zero rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to sort rows of matrix according to a number of non zero elements in the rows consider the following example where

```
 a = [0 0 2;2 1 4;2 5 0]
```

but a should be

```
a =

 2     1     4
 2     5     0
 0     0     2
```

in the end , here is what i have come up with

```
 for i = 1:3
    vec(i) = sum(a(i,:)==0);%to get number of nonzero elementsin each row
 end
 a = [a vec.']
 a = sortrows(a,4) % sorting according to number of nonzero elements 
 a = [a(:,1:3)]
```

the code above works but does anyone have a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
[~,I] = sort(sum(a~=0,2), 'descend');
a = a(I,:);
```

Result:

```
 a =

 2     1     4
 2     5     0
 0     0     2
```

Comment: Thanks that was a much better way!